# Getting error when using directory to retrieve image

Tags: ios, directory, save, uicollectionview

I am trying to recall the image that I have saved inside the directory to show it in a UICollectionView.  This is the code to do that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Hats";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
        }}}
```

However I am getting warnings that is showing in the last line telling me that Local declaration of allImagesArray hides instance Variables.  I do not know why this is happening.  If you want to see my other codes then feel free to ask.  Any help is greatly appreciated.
This is for my .h file

```
@interface HatsViewController : UICollectionViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *allImagesArray;

 }
```

Comment: Show how you are defining `allImagesArray` in the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably declaring it inside your interface file - allImagesArray is already "known" by your UIViewController.

What Xcode is saying with the warning is saying is something like: *"Hey, you are already declaring it, and in your `viewDidLoad` you are doing it again! Be careful"*

To fix it, just initiate your array this way:

Instead of `NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Replace it by `allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

**BINGO Update: Indeed, as you just put here, you already declare it in the interface file, so you don't need to declare it again in `viewDidLoad`**